# Consider the following PHP function declaration

Tags: php

```
function f1($a){
    if (count($a) == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return array_shift($a)+f1($a);
    }
}
```

Note: The `array_shift()` function removes the first element (the element at index 0) from an array and returns the value of the removed element.
What would be the return value when this function is called as f1(array(1,2,3,4,5,6))?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Is this an exam question at your school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "recursive function" that adds up all the values inside the array.

Please read this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

In this case the result is 21.